# Functions & Class inheritance

Tags: python

I'm following the first Udacity course and **believe** I've followed all of their instructions but am getting an error.

```
AttributeError: 'MainPage' object has no attribute 'render'
```

My code is below. In the video, it works for them, but I don't understand why. As I read this code, it seems that `render` is inside the `Handler` class, and I'm trying to call it inside the `MainPage` class.

Why does it work for them and not for me?

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'html_templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader= jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir)) 



class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def write(self, *a, **kw):
    self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
      t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
      return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
      self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
  def get(self):
    self.render("shopping_list.html")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                              ],
                              debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods `render_str` and `render` are indented too far, so they are inside the `write` method.  Move them out so they are at the same indentation level as `def write` (or indent the `write` method more so it's at the same level as the other two).

Comment: ARAGAH!! Gawd McDabbit. That was it. Thank you.

Comment: I'll mark it as answered as soon as I can.

Comment: @MorganAllen note that four spaces per level of indentation, as recommended by the official style guide, makes this much more visually obvious than the two you're currently using.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jon, and yes, I'll be doing that !! :-)